# Different Decision tree pruning methods

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-science, decision-tree, pruning

I am trying to learn different pruning methods for decision tree. I got list of methods,below is the list.

```
1.Reduced Error Pruning
2.Cost Complexity pruning
3.Minimum error pruning
4.Pessimistic Error Pruning
5.Critical Value Pruning
6.Error Based pruning
```

I got enough content to learn first to algorithms but unable to get enough content and understand other algorithms. Can any one help me out to understand these algorithms thoroughly? Also, which algorithms are mostly used for pruning and why?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Google is your friend here. Searching for Critical Value Pruning revealed https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1022604100933.pdf, which discusses several of the methods that you identified. Searches on other of your methods revealed lots of relevant information. Time to start reading.

Comment: Thak you for your suggestion. I have already checked this out and have already googled everything but neither this nor other documents or sites are good enough to understand all these algorithms.

Comment: It's unlikely that you're going to find somebody here who has and is willing to give you the information you'll find online or in books. This site is for asking about specific problems. It's not a deep research site. If you have a specific question about implementing one of those algorithms, then this is the right place. According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, your question just isn't on topic. My suggestion is to keep searching and study carefully what you find.